# Firestore: Searching the element inside document array if it exists or not

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am having collection with some documents. Each document contains some arrays with strings. I want to know whether given string is there inside the specific document array. I have seen queries to find the documents by using array contains. But I have the document I just want to query whether the string exists inside that document array or not?

```
 var dbRef = dbConnection.db.collection('posts').doc(req.body.post_id);
dbRef.where('likes', 'array-contains', req.body.user_id).get()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

I have a document with specific id. I know the document id. That document contains array named as likes. That array will store some strings. I want to know the whether the string exists or not inside that array or not? I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: dbRef.where is not a function
```

Then I tried without giving document id. It worked. It returned the documents. But I want to search inside the document array

Comment: please post the code you have tried so far and the problemetic area.

Comment: @AshishModi I edited the question. Can please check is there any problem in my query.

Comment: If you want to know if an array field in a single document contains some value, just read the document and examine the array in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dbRef` points to a (single) document, and you can't query a document.

If you want to query the documents in the `posts` collection, you're looking for:

```
var dbRef = dbConnection.db.collection('posts');
dbRef.where('likes', 'array-contains', req.body.user_id).get()
  ...
```

You can **query** for both document ID and array contains with:

```
db.collection('books').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
var dbRef = dbConnection.db.collection('posts');
dbRef
  .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', req.body.post_id)
  .where('likes', 'array-contains', req.body.user_id).get()
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can simply read the document with your original code, and then check client-side whether the array still contains the field:

```
var dbRef = dbConnection.db.collection('posts').doc(req.body.post_id);
dbRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc.data().likes.indexOf(req.body.user_id) >= 0) {
          ... the post is liked by the user
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```